# Different styles of page numbering in one book

Tags: page-numbering, books

I'm writing a book and I want the following:

In the table of contents / preface / etc: odd page numbers in the bottom right and even page numbers in the top left. (In small letters. For example, page 9 is written "ix").

In the chapters: odd page numbers in the top right and even page numbers in the top left. (In arabaic numbers).

How can I do this?

Comment: `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` switches, perhaps? (You mean roman page numbers, i.e. i, ii, iii, iv, etc.)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm already using \frontmatter and \mainmatter switches but I don't know how to make fancyhdr to that.

Comment: Providing a MWE which shows what you have done so far would be **very** helpful ;-)

Comment: Thanks man. I had only used \frontmatter and \mainmatter. I knew how to do it properly in the main matter or in the front matter but not in both. Will post MWE next time!

Comment: Neither `\frontmatter` nor `\mainmatter` has a direct influence on the positions of the page numbers, basically it's `pagenumbering` and `secnumdepth`, which is influenced

Comment: Right. I just didn't knew I could use if and else like that! So nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}



\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \if@mainmatter  % Is it mainmatter -- yes
  \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}  % Right odd page header
  \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}  % Left even page header
  \else
  \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}  % Right odd page footer
  \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}  % Right even page header
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\blindtext[10]
\clearpage
\mainmatter

\chapter{First}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```